# How to easily find layer by NAME in Aftereffects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, animation, adobe-after-effects

Ok, I have over 100 layers in the AI file Im trying to animate in AE and I have a problem. If Im looking for the layer named "head" for example, I have no way to find it except scrolling through all layers. This is inefficient.

Is there any way (without a script) to quickly find & select an AE layer? I have the command F search bar, but searching there does no good:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The search bar on top of the layers in the timeline doesn't search just layer names... It's useful for searching for specific properties (such as "color" or "path"), or just about anything else under a layer (comments for example) but it *does* search based on layer name too.

[image]

It's worth noting that the search only affects *selected* layers; so if you want to search through all layers, either select all or make sure no layers are selected (this trips me up occasionally, where search isn't working and it turns out I've got a single layer selected).

You can read more in the Adobe help:

- [**Managing layers in After Effects**](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/layers.html)
- [**Search and filter in the Timeline, Project, and Effects & Presets panels**](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/general-user-interface-items.html#search_and_filter_in_the_timeline_project_and_effects_presets_panels)